# Joining objects in v4.0 - temp_override?

Tags: python, objects

In one of my scripts, which worked fine before v4.0, I join several objects together.  The original code segment looked like this:

```
for thisObjectType in obs:
    ctx = bpy.context.copy()
    thisObjList = obs[thisObjectType]
    ctx['active_object'] = thisObjList[0]
    ctx['selected_editable_objects'] = thisObjList
    bpy.ops.object.join(ctx)
```

However, since v4.0, the code now fails with a "ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported", which I believe relates to the subsequent update regarding bpy.context.temp_override().  As such, in line with what I've understood from the documentation, I've now tried changing that last line to:

```
with bpy.context.temp_override(**ctx):
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

However, it now fails with "TypeError: Area not found in screen" at the same point in the code, which seems to suggest that it's somehow looking in the wrong place.  If that's the case, I don't really understand what it's now expecting instead.  So, does anyone have any suggestions for a solution?

Regards,

Guy Heathcote

Comment: Not to worry, I think I've now solved it.   Along with the code change I showed in my original post, the line 'ctx = bpy.context.copy()' also seemingly needs to be changed to 'ctx = bpy.context.scene.copy()'.  

I don't really understand why this is now additionally required...I was just trying some random options until something worked.